# How to multiply Data in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

How do I multiply Data in Datatables ?
I have Datatables and javascript that look like this:

```
$('#xxdata').DataTable( {
        "destroy": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
            url  : "xxreport.php",
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                datedari : SplitRange[0].trim(),
                datesampai : SplitRange[1].trim()
        }
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "offerName" },
                { "data": "offerCountry" },
                { "data": "visits" },
                { "data": "conversions" },
                { "data": "profit"}
        ]
} );
```

> I want to multiply data in `{ "data": "profit"}` 
>  maybe like
>   this `{ "data": "profit" * 0.7}`

Can I change data in datatables as I want? Or can anyone give other solutions?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to just multiply it when you first obtain the data or on some event trigger?

Comment: Have you tried to do it the way you describe, and found that it doesn't work?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to just multiply it when first obtain data

Comment: @Zayn That's pretty easy then, with `columns.render`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Chris Hahah it's okay, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `columns.render` option ([documented here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)) to do this.

```
"columns": [
            { "data": "offerName" },
            { "data": "offerCountry" },
            { "data": "visits" },
            { "data": "conversions" },
            { "data": "profit",
              "render": function (data) {
                            return data * 0.7;
                        }
            }
    ]
```

In this case, `data` in the function signature represents the data for the cell. There are other options that can be passed into the function, but in your case these do not need to be included since this is such a simple operation. See the documentation link if you ever want to expand to a more complicated rendering function

Answer (score 0):

You must add a render to your column, something like this:

```
{ "data": "profit", "render": renderMyProfit}
```

and you should have the rendering function declared before you call the .DataTable() function.

```
 var renderMyProfit = function (data, type, row, meta) {
            var renderContent = "<div>*</div>";
            return renderContent.replace("*", row.profit * 0.7);
  };
```

Comment: Why are you doing a whole replace on the `renderContent`? You can just return the data directly.

Comment: Chris, If you have a more complex need than multiplying a number, then you´ll already have a html return in place, this can be helpful to most of people.

Comment: You really shouldn't be injecting HTML into DataTables source data, note that this isn't just an HTML table but a table enhanced by the DataTables jQuery plugin which handles formatting for you.

Comment: Chris, you got it wrong. If you look at the link https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render, in the examples section, there are lots of examples using render in order to return html. That´s what it is meant to be.

Comment: There is a link and a span, I'm not sure that qualifies as lots of examples, and obviously links have to be encoded in HTML, but fair enough.